# Moving and organizing Java codes on another files

Tags: java, game-development

I would like to create a new file and put this block of action buttons codes to be organized on the other files i dont know how i would be able to move it.

Iam making this code and its a little bit disorganized and im having a hard time on what is their purpose.

Is there any other easier method to create a actionlistener codes?

> 

```
public void buttonAction (){
        
        
        bgButton[0].addActionListener(e -> {
            
            bgPanel[0].setVisible(false);
            bgPanel[0].remove(bgButton[0]);
            bgPanel[1].setVisible(true);
            
        });
        
        
        
        
            
        for (int a = 3,c=0 ; a <12; a++, c++){
            
            final int b=c;
            final int d=a;
        bgButton[a].addActionListener(e -> {
            
            
            if (input>=0&&input <=9&&Num[b]!=0){
            input = Num[b]*10;
            
                if(input!=0)
                    
                    createObject(1,12,283,245,85,61,numFile[b]);//12
                    bgButton[d].setEnabled(false);
                    Number[b]=-1;
            } else if (input >9&&input<100&&input%10==0&&Num[b]!=0&&buttonClicked){
                input += Num[b];
                buttonClicked = !buttonClicked;
                createObject(1,13,432,245,85,61,numFile[b]);//13
                bgButton[d].setEnabled(false);
                    Number[b]=-1;
                    
            }else if (Num[b]==0&&buttonClicked){
                
                input += Num[b];
                createObject(1,13,432,245,85,61,numFile[b]);//13
                bgButton[d].setEnabled(false);
                buttonClicked = !buttonClicked;
                Number[b]=-1;
                
            }
            
            System.err.println("total  " + input);
            bgPanel[1].revalidate();
            bgPanel[1].repaint();
                    });
        
        }
        
        
        
        bgButton[14].addActionListener(e -> {
            
            for (int c =0 ,a=3; c <9; a++,c++){
                final int b = a;
                final int d=c;
                
                int firstNum = input/10;
                int secondNum=input%10;
                
                
                if (Number[c]==-1&&bgButton[13]!=null){
                    
                    attack = input;
                    
                    generateSoloNum(d);
                    bgButton[b].setEnabled(true);
                    updateButtonIcon(b,64,48,numFile[d]);
                    bgPanel[1].remove(bgButton[12]);
                    
                    bgPanel[1].remove(bgButton[13]);
                    bgPanel[1].revalidate();
                    bgPanel[1].repaint();
                    
                    Number [c]=0;
                    
                    input =0;
                    
                }
                
                
                
            }
            buttonClicked = true;
            bgButton[13]=null;
        });
        
        
        createObject(1,15,149,244,50,38,"res/imageAssets/x.png");//15
        
        bgButton[15].addActionListener(e -> {
            input = 0;
            bgPanel[1].remove(bgButton[12]);
            bgPanel[1].remove(bgButton[13]);
            bgPanel[1].revalidate();
            bgPanel[1].repaint();
            buttonClicked = true;
            for (int a = 3,c=0; a<12;a++,c++){
                bgButton[a].setEnabled(true);
                Number [c]=0;
            }
        });
        
    }
```

I tried import Main.UI; and import Main.Action;

Action is the new file that i want to move it into.

tried using chat gpt but it makes no sense

Comment: For game development, I would recommend (J)OGL (Open GL for Java) over Swing. The other thing I would advise is to learn about the `Model View Controller` pattern. Under MVC, I would recommend that you not move your ActionListeners to another class, but instead implement them as one line methods that call methods in the Controller (which may be the same as the Model and the View) and do modularity that way

Comment: Will try that next time my deadline is near

Answer (score 1):

All methods in Java need to be associated with a class.  You cannot move methods from listeners into separate files.

You can create separate listener implementations that include these action methods.  If you refactor that way you'll give instances of those listener implementations to your Swing frame and call them instead of keeping them in one big Swing class.

I think this is a good idea.  You would change implementations by injecting new classes instead of modifying the frame code.

Each of those `addActionListener` lambdas would become part of separate classes.

Swing UI code tends to turn into walls of code if you're not careful.  I have never seen a well decomposed Swing UI application posted here.

Comment: I only know how to refractor variable names and I cant mostly comprehend of what you just have said